# resultants over finite fields vs resultants over their closure

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, finite-fields

I'm having a little trouble grokking the following line of argument. I have two monic, univariate polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ that share a common root, where $p$ is prime. I want to imply that they must therefore have a common root over $\mathbb{C}$. I am told that the proof of this involves resultants and minimal polynomials, but I am missing the nub of the argument. Why is it so? Any help shedding some light on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: You mean they share a common root over $\mathbb Z / p \mathbb Z$ for *every* prime $p$? (Which I would rather not denote by the same letter as one of the polynomials.)

Comment: Also, I take it your two polynomials $p,q$ originally belong to $\Bbb Z[X]$?

Comment: Bezout's identity. To any two polynomials $p,q$ with rational coefficients there exist polynomials $u,v$ with rational coefficients such that $$up+vq=d,$$ where $d$ is the greatest common divisor of $p$ and $q$ in the ring $\Bbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: Darij, for a particular prime $p$, obviously. Olivier, yes. Jyrki, how does this help? I'm having a little trouble seeing the connection.

Answer (score 1):

So we are given two polynomials $p(x),q(x)\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$ such that when reduced modulo any prime $\ell$ they share a common root in $\Bbb{Z}/\ell\Bbb{Z}$. The claim is that they must have a common complex zero.

Assume contrariwise that $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ do not share a common complex zero. Because $\Bbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, this means that the greatest common divisor
$m(x)=\gcd(p(x),q(x)$ must be constant $1$.

By Bezout's identity there exists polynomials $u(x),v(x)\in\Bbb{Q}[x]$ such that
$$
u(x)p(x)+v(x)q(x)=m(x)=1.
$$
(If you have not heard Bezout's name associated with this fact you can alternatively recall that the ring $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ is a principal ideal domain, and $m(x)$ is a generator of the ideal $\langle p(x),q(x)\rangle$).

In general the polynomials $u(x),v(x)$ have rational coefficients. But they have only finitely many terms, so the denominators of those coefficients have a least common multiple $d$. So multiplying the above equation by $d$ we get polynomials
$U(x)=du(x),V(x)=dv(x)\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$ such that
$$
U(x)p(x)+V(x)q(x)=d.\qquad(*)
$$

Now let us choose the prime $\ell$ such that $\ell\nmid d$. It follows that $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ cannot have a common zero in $\Bbb{Z}/\ell\Bbb{Z}$. For if the residue class $\overline{a}$ where such a zero, then the integers $p(a)$ and $q(a)$ would both be divisible by $\ell$. This contradicts the equation $(*)$, because its left hand side
$U(a)p(a)+V(a)q(a)$ would then also be divisible by $\ell$, but the right hand side is not.

This is the desired contradiction, and the claim follows.

---

Initially it was unclear whether the assumption should hold for all primes $\ell$. This cannot be relaxed essentially (well, it is sufficient if this is known to hold for infinitely many primes $\ell$). Most certainly a single prime won't do. For example $p(x)=x+1$ and $q(x)=x+4$ share the root $x=2$ modulo $\ell=3$, but the obviously do not share any complex zeros. I leave it as an exercise to generalize this example to one that
works for a given finite set of primes.

Comment: IIRC the smallest possible $d$ is the resultant of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ in the ring $\Bbb{Z}[x]$. For the purposes of this question any $d$ will do.